# Phonegap keeps showing Confirm dialog

Tags: android, cordova, webview, dialog, confirm

I use Phonegap 2.0. In my Android application is my main activity which extends from DroidGap

I have an asset html file which includes phonegap2.0.0.js
It is OK when I use

```
appView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

But when I read that file into String, then load it using

```
appView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://foo", html, "text/html", "utf8", "");
```

Phonegap shows many dialog (getPort, getToken, ...) then keeps showing Confirm dialog

How to solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I see that Confirm dialog is made in `onJsConfirm` method in **CordovaChromeClient** class. What is that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CordovaWebView does not currently support loadDataWithBaseURL. This is using an uninitialized WebView which is sending everything to the JS Prompt code. I would recommend adding a ticket to the Cordova tracker [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB)

Comment: What is ticket? The link you provided shows something related to Globalization plugin ?

Comment: Ticket usually means bug report submission (to project's bugtracker).